# Is there a way to easily covert a GeoTIFF to an 8 byte format. I am using QGis 3.XX

Tags: gis, qgis

Trying to publish a GeoTIFF for a tiled Web application but I am getting error that too many bytes

I can't work out if there is an easy way to do it without delving into the world of command line GDAL.  Surely there are some settings that can be used in the convert raster tool.

Comment: Remember: if you get an error, show the actual error [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), and talk about _what_ is throwing errors. "Web application" doesn't tell anyone _which_ application you're talking about.